# Problem with linking static and dynamic Fortran library with f2py

Tags: python, linker, fortran, libraries, f2py

I am using the [library](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3440) written by M. Wimmer to compute pfaffians.

I have big code in python, in which I invoke the function from the package pfaffian.

However, I need to compute these pfaffians many times, therefore I would like to increase efficiency (using profiler I checked that computation of pfaffian consumes much time).

Therefore, I would like to use f2py tool to invoke functions from Fortran library in python code. The problem is, that I need only function skpfa which depends on other functions which belong to the library.

I tried to use instructions from [here](https://modelingguru.nasa.gov/docs/DOC-2343) to link with static library libpfapack.a, however while importing the output module (which I called pfaf.so) I got the error message:

```
    ./pfaf.so: undefined symbol: skpfa_
```

I read that the problem can lie in the fact that I want to link static library, therefore I created dynamical library from provided sources using command:

```
    gfortran -O3 -fimplicit-none -c -fPIC file.f -o file.o
```

for all source files, and then

```
    gfortran -shared $(OBJECTS) -o libpfapack
```

I created following signature file pfaf.pyf:

```
    python MODULE pfaffian 
       PUBLIC
       INTERFACE
          SUBROUTINE SKPFA(A, PFSFF, UPLO, MTHD, INFO)

             double precision, intent(in) :: A(:,:)
             double precision, intent(inout) :: p
             character, intent(in), optional :: UPLO, MTHD
             integer, intent(out), optional :: info
          end subroutine skpfa
        end interface
    end python module pfaffian
```

and I invoked:

```
    f2py -c --lower --fcompiler=gnu95 pfaf.pyf -L{path to directory with    libpfapack} -lpfapack
```

and I got a message

```
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpfapack
```

If I invoke f2py command without -lpfapack the things compile and produce file pfaf.so, however I get an error in python :

> ./pfaf.so: undefined symbol: skpfa_.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?